# unrecognised content at end of stream with PNG

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, png, readfile

I'm new to use PNG and I get below error unrecognised content at end of stream

```
cy.readFile("cypress/e2e/Testdata/sample.png", "binary").then((image1) => {
      cy.readFile("cypress/downloads/sample.png", "binary").then((image2) => {
        const img1 = PNG.sync.read(image1);
        const img2 = PNG.sync.read(image2);
        const { width, height } = img1;
        const diff = new PNG({ width, height });
    
        pixelmatch(img1.data, img2.data, diff.data, width, height, {
          threshold: 0.1,
        });
    
        fs.writeFileSync("diff.png", PNG.sync.write(diff));
        expect(diff.width).to.equal(0);
        expect(diff.height).to.equal(0);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot mix browser commands like `cy.readfile()` with node commands like `fs.writeFileSync()`.

You will have to create a [Cypress task](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task) to run this code.

```js
module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        png({image1Path, image2Path}) {

          const image1 = fs.readFileSync(image1Path)
          const image2 = fs.readFileSync(image2Path)

          const img1 = PNG.sync.read(image1);
          const img2 = PNG.sync.read(image2);
    
          const { width, height } = img1;
          const diff = new PNG({ width, height });
    
          pixelmatch(img1.data, img2.data, diff.data, width, height, {
            threshold: 0.1,
          });
    
          fs.writeFileSync("diff.png", PNG.sync.write(diff));

          return diff
        },
      })
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I have updated my code but my task is never ending. could you please help me.

Task:
cy.task("png", {
      image1Path: "cypress/downloads/PurolatorLabelStore1.png",
      image2Path: "cypress/downloads/PurolatorLabelStore1.png",
    },{ timeout: 50000 }).then((textOrNull) => {
      expect(textOrNull).to.equal(0);

Comment: Its keep on loading

Comment: You will need to take a closer look at the examples for PNG package, unfortunately this is not the place for a complete tutorial on how to use it correctly.